# How to get the mac address of HoloLens 2 in Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, hololens, unreal-blueprint, unrealscript

I would like to get the mac address of HoloLens 2 in Unreal Engine using either C++ or blueprint. Is there a way to get the mac address/serial number or any sort of solution to identify the uniqueness of the device?

Answer (score 0):

Since HoloLens App is a UWP app, you can use WinRT API methods contains in WinSDK. For example, you want to get the identifier of the local device would need [EasClientDeviceInformation.Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.id?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Security_ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning_EasClientDeviceInformation_Id) in [Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning?view=winrt-19041) namespace. For how to include WinRT libraries in your Unreal project, please see [WinRT in Unreal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unreal/unreal-winrt?tabs=426)